# Call another property within the same template helpers object

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Normally we can do this in a normal object:

```
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: function() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
console.log( obj.b() );  // Output '2' in console
```

So we can get value of obj.a inside obj.b.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Meteor Blaze. In the template:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
    {{b}}
</template>
```

and in the code behind:

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
    a: 2,
    b: function() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

Rendering 'mytemplate' will NOT output '2' as expected. How can I call 'a' method from 'b' function definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your object is not preserved in any way.

See [in Blaze code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/blaze/template.js#L439):

```
Template.prototype.helpers = function (dict) {
  for (var k in dict)
    this.__helpers.set(k, dict[k]);
};
```

I think that functions are also applied to the template data (using `this` leads you to the data passed to the template) so even the original context of your method `b` is kaboom since `this` is dynamically evaluated. The behaviour you want to achieve is not possible with this structure.

You could maybe try to bind this method to its original object `obj.b = b.bind(obj)` but that's hideous.
Also Blaze may not like dealing with bound functions.

To solve this use two different objects: One for the data, one for the helper methods.

```
var data, methods;

data = { a : 2 };
methods = { b : function() { return data.a; } };

Template.myTemplate.helpers(methods);
```

In a more general way avoid relying on `this` when not explicitly supported by the API you use... Unless you try to force your way by `bind`ing it.

Comment: This is counter-intuitive and inconvenient, but I guess that's a trade-off to have `this` refer to the template's context data.